# TFS - HPQC Bi-Directional Integration

Tags: tfs, integration, hp-quality-center

Can bug in TFS be integrated with defects in HP ALM in a two-way manner? If yes, how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Its very much feasible. Either you can go with existing solutions available in market. Or you can build your own with the help of APIs provided by both of the systems. Both systems are very rich in terms of communication interfaces. 
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts
You can work with this and figureout your way. Else there are very good tools available to do this.